# Can you retaliate in any way when a civ breaks its promise?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civ6, can you retaliate in any way (or does the other civ suffer any other penalty, such as damaged reputation) when a civilization breaks a promise?

For example I asked another civ several times not to convert my cities to their religion (while we were allied to each other!) and they broke that promise repeatedly. It didn't seem like there was anything official I could do about it, other than denouncing them once our alliance ended.

The annoying thing is that I wasn't even able to break the alliance early, so I had to wait a long time to have a Holy War Casus Belli against them for violating the promise.

Comment: I wish and hope Casus Belli includes many more reasons like these broken promises in future patches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now (after Fall 2016 update), there's nothing official you can do.  There are related Casus Belli, such as a Holy War if they've converted one of your cities, but I believe this requires you to have founded a religion of your own.

My typical response is to beat them up and live with the warmongering penalty, but perhaps that is not always the answer.